# Select closest input with query

Tags: jquery

I have a form see below

```
<div id="upload_image_sets">
  <div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
    <input type="text" id="upload_image_link_1" class="image" size="36" name="hero_options[upload_image_link_1]" value="' . $hero_options['upload_image_link_1'] . '" />
    <input id="show_upload_image_link_button_1" class="button upload_images" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
    <div class="actions">
      <button class="clone">Clone</button> 
      <button class="remove">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you click clone, it adds another form and every 1 in that form increments, when you click the Upload Image button it takes you to a wordpress media uploader where you select an image and it's pasts the url in the input with the id upload_image_link_1

This works fine when it's just 1 input, but as the form add more fields i need to select the input that matches the upload image button

Here's the jquery

```
var custom_uploader;
$('.upload_images').click(function(e) {
    var ter = $(this).siblings('input').attr('id');
    e.preventDefault();
    //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
    if (custom_uploader) {
        custom_uploader.open();
     return;
    }
    //Extend the wp.media object
    custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
    title: 'Choose Image',
    button: {
        text: 'Choose Image'
    },
     multiple: false
});
//When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
    attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
    $('#upload_image_link_1').val(attachment.url);
    alert (this);

    });
    //Open the uploader dialog
    custom_uploader.open();
});
```

The line that i'm having trouble with is

```
$('#upload_image_link_1').val(attachment.url);
```

I just don't know what to try

Comment: when you clone the elements , you are probably creating  a new input fields i guess which would have a different id for the text box holding the url. but in your uploader code i can see that you are using  a static id each time. which needs to be a dynamic id

Comment: The id for both the button and input box end with a number, once it's cloned the number increases, I've made a class for the button to make the selection easier but I still need to select the input box somehow

Comment: if the ids are unique for each set of cloned elements, then why are you using a static id here ` $('#upload_image_link_1').val(attachment.url);` ? dont you think this id should be the id of the sibling input text box. in your upload button click , you are capturing the text box`s id  inside `ter` but you havent used it anywhere,so do one thing, declare this `ter` outside the click callback function and refer the value inside `custom_uploader.on()` like this `$('#'+ter).val(attachment.url);`.

Comment: @dreamweiver Thanks for the input, the static id was put there to test it was working, I tried changing it to ter but I know know that I made and error, I was adding '#'+ in front of it, it's now working thanks to you, although I am getting an issue which I'll have to make a separate post in a minute once I make a fiddle up, when i clone the form, the upload_image button won't wok until the page is saved which isn't good enough. Thanks

Comment: Good to know that, lets close this question, this would reduce the No of Open Questions from SO. regarding the new post keep me notified.

Comment: @dreamweiver Thanks for your help, if you are at all interested, here's the link to my next question, i'll mark this as answered thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067000/cloning-forms-button-not-working-when-it-should-and-not-displaying-correctly-on

Comment: Answered a bit prematurely, when adding an image, rather than select the input box next to the button, it adds the url to the first box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$('#upload_image_link_1').val(attachment.url);
```

to

```
$('#'+ter).val(attachment.url);
```

add

```
var ter = $(this).siblings('input').attr('id');
```

above the line

```
custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
```

This will now work

Answer (score 0):

For any dynamically generated elements, you need to use `.on` instead of `.click`. more precisely `.on` is used for delegated events.

---

**Article from official Jquery site:**

***Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().** To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler.*

*Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.*

this example attaches a handler to 1,000 elements:

```
  $( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
       alert( $( this ).text() );
  });
```

A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked tr to tbody):

```
  $( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
       alert( $( this ).text() );
  });
```

**REF:**

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Happy Coding:)

Comment: I tried the .on but I couldn't get it to work with my script, do you have any input as to how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

The target input is the previous sibling of the clicked upload button so try

```
var custom_uploader;
$('.upload_images').click(function (e) {
    var ter = $(this).siblings('input').attr('id'),
        //the clicked button reference is stored here
        $this = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
    if (custom_uploader) {
        custom_uploader.open();
        return;
    }
    //Extend the wp.media object
    custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Choose Image',
        button: {
            text: 'Choose Image'
        },
        multiple: false
    });
    //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    custom_uploader.on('select', function () {
        attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        //the target input is the previous sibling of the clicked upload button
        $this.prev().val(attachment.url);
        alert(this);

    });
    //Open the uploader dialog
    custom_uploader.open();
});
```